# Alternative to deprecated Facebook /notes/ endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

I had been using the (now deprecated) /notes/ end point in the Graph API to fetch and aggregate "notes" documents in specific public pages. Since this no longer functions as of Jan. 28 2015, I built an alternative method using the "get Notes via RSS". Pulling an RSS feed of the page's notes and parsing them as JSON objects. This new function appears to work well but my question is this:

Will the "Notes" app continue to exist as a Facebook Page feature in the future? or does the deprecation of the Notes Graph API endpoint foretell "Notes" ultimate demise.

Also will the Notes RSS feed continue to be available? or will this service be deprecated as well.

Hoping someone from the Facebook development team can shed some light...

Comment: Why not contact the FB development team or community directly then?  Voting to close this as too localized.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is really a question for the FB dev team/community and too localized for SO.

Comment: Ya I did that not long after in the Facebook developers  group and got several relatively useful responses here: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/845942988782550/ Thanks